# Laravel: Include template with variable name

Tags: php, laravel

I want to include a partial based on the name of variable.

controller passes a variable `$foo` with value partials. x.

> $type = x;

then i change it to the partials name.

> $template = "partials.{$type}";

in views, i have a partial directory.

I want to include a partials depending on the value or with the value of $foo

> @include({{$template}});

which is similar to the following

> @include('partials.x');

but it gives me error

Comment: <?php echo $__env->make(<?php echo $template; ?>, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>

FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ')'

Comment: Are you doing this - $template = "partials.{$type}"; in your controller?

Comment: well, both are same. you can use either way for this. in the end $template is having the desired value. $template = 'partails.x'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `@include({{$template}});`, you should write:

```
@include($template);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your controller

$template = "partials".$type;

Rather than using blade syntax there.

Comment: i am not using this in controller. i am using this in blade view

@include('partials.x')

Comment: I mentioned in my question that i want to include a partial with whatever value $template has

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass variable to the view and put in `@include`

```
// controller
$viewToInclude = 'some.view';
return View:: ... ->with('includeMe', $viewToInclude);

// view
@include($includeMe);
```